# Connection to SQL Azure with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, azure-sql-database

I am failing to connect to SQL Azure using Delphi 2010 and dbGo. What is wrong and how to resolve that ?

The details:

The TADOConnection with the following connection string (the login info is changed):

`Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security="";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=me@tyasdgerj5;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=tcp:tyasdgerj5.database.windows.net;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""`

Returns the following error text:

Server name cannot be determined.  It must appear as the first segment of the server's dns name (servername.database.windows.net).  Some libraries do not send the server name, in which case the server name must be included as part of the user name (username@servername).  In addition, if both formats are used, the server names must match..

Note, that SQL Server Management Studio connects without problems.

Comment: With no details of the errors you are getting, it is difficult to provide any guidance.

Comment: You did put user@servername.database.windows.net in the SQL user name right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far I know dbGo does not support SQL Azure.

The only component that support it, it's AnyDAC look at [this](http://www.da-soft.com/forums/anydac-general-english/microsoft-sql-azure.html) or better yet [this](http://www.da-soft.com/blogs/delphi-sql-azure-support.html) explaining.

Best regards

Comment: could anyone please say , what happened to anydac? i found this : http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/embarcadero_buys_anydac.html saying Embarcadero bought anydac in 2013, and intend to integrate with delphi. while i cant see a component anydac in the new delphi versions. it seems to be firedac from xe5.

Comment: That's right, Embarcadero renamed AnyDAC to FireDAC